# try/catch-block without any effect

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

As I assume, try/catch should perform code which is defined in catch-block,if there is any error in try-block,correct?
Following code won't do that.It will be thrown out error-in this case:

```
Getting unknown property: common\modules\lookup\models\LAnrede::anreden
```

Any ideas,how to fix this respectively what I did wrong?

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\modules\bewerber\models\Bewerber;
use common\modules\basis\models\Person;
use common\modules\lookup\models\LAnrede;
use yii\base\ErrorException;
use kartik\widgets\Alert;

try {
    $query_one = LAnrede::find()->innerJoin('Person', 'l_anrede.id = Person.id_anrede')->one();
    $query_all = LAnrede::find()->innerJoin('Person', 'l_anrede.id = Person.id_anrede')->all();

    var_dump($query_one);
    var_dump($query_all);

    echo"<h3>Anrede_one:" . $query_one->anrede . "</h3>";
    $x = 1;
    foreach ($query_all as $attributes) {
        echo "<br><label>Anrede_all_$x:<br>" . $attributes->anreden . "</label>";
        $x++;
    }
} catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
    echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
        'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
        'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
        'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
        'showSeparator' => true,
        'delay' => false
    ]);
}
?>
```

A hint for ponury-kostek:

I programmed in class LAnrede for each method try/catch-Block. No effect!
Here is model/class LAnrede

```html
<?php

namespace common\modules\lookup\models\base;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;
use mootensai\behaviors\UUIDBehavior;
use yii\base\ErrorException;
use kartik\widgets\Alert;

/**
 * This is the base model class for table "l_anrede".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $anrede
 *
 * @property \common\modules\lookup\models\Person[] $people
 */
class LAnrede extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    use \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait;

    /**
     * This function helps \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait runs faster
     * @return array relation names of this model
     */
    public function relationNames() {
        try {
            return [
                'people'
            ];
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        try {
            return [
                [['anrede'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
                [['optimistic_lock'], 'default', 'value' => '0'],
                [['optimistic_lock'], 'mootensai\components\OptimisticLockValidator']
            ];
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName() {
        try {
            return 'l_anrede';
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     * overwrite function optimisticLock
     * return string name of field are used to stored optimistic lock
     *
     */
    public function optimisticLock() {
        try {
            return 'optimistic_lock';
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        try {
            return [
                'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
                'anrede' => Yii::t('app', 'Anrede'),
            ];
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPeople() {
        try {
            return $this->hasMany(\common\modules\basis\models\Person::className(), ['id_anrede' => 'id']);
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        try {
            return [
                'timestamp' => [
                    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                    'createdAtAttribute' => 'angelegt_am',
                    'updatedAtAttribute' => 'aktualisiert_am',
                    'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'),
                ],
                'blameable' => [
                    'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                    'createdByAttribute' => 'angelegt_von',
                    'updatedByAttribute' => 'aktualisiert_von',
                ],
                'uuid' => [
                    'class' => UUIDBehavior::className(),
                    'column' => 'id',
                ],
            ];
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return \common\modules\lookup\models\LAnredeQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find() {
        try {
            return new \common\modules\lookup\models\LAnredeQuery(get_called_class());
        } catch (ErrorException $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            echo Alert::widget([//informiere den Anwender,daß kein Datensatz gefunden wurde
                'type' => Alert::TYPE_DANGER,
                'title' => 'Konfigurationsfehler',
                'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign',
                'body' => 'Dem angemeldeten User ist in der Mitarbeitertabelle kein Mitarbeiter zugeordnet<br><br>' . $error,
                'showSeparator' => true,
                'delay' => false
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `try` block youre using `$attributes->anreden`. Propably there's no column with this name in your database (or you still have db cache). Pointing to the question, why `try/catch` didn't worked - because youre trying to catch wrong exception. Youre trying to catch `yii\base\ErrorException`, but it's `'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException` exception. To handle it right, you should catch 'all-in-one' or expand your `catch` block:

**All in one:**

```
} catch(\Exception $error) {
```

---

**Expanded:**

```
} catch (ErrorException $error) {
    // do some stuff here
} catch (\yii\base\UnknownPropertyException $error) {
    // do some another stuff here
} catch (\Exception $error) {
    // do some stuff with any other exceptions
}
```

Comment: Great.ur the best.I will give u positive response in this forum

Answer (score 1):

It's because line that causes error `use common\modules\lookup\models\LAnrede;` is outside try/catch block.

More precisely you have error in file that is imported by `common\modules\lookup\models\LAnrede` that's why try/catch block can't
catch error. Fix error in `LAnrede`.

Comment: Häh? Everything is in try block!! Look code exactly,please

Comment: No effect.See below

Comment: Add content of `common\modules\lookup\models\LAnrede` to your question

Comment: I just have added content

Comment: Try add `'enableSchemaCache' => false` to your DB config

Comment: I can't find bug in `common\modules\lookup\models\LAnrede` because I don't know Yii. But im sure that error is caused outside try/catch block. Try to comment out `$query_one = ...` and `$query_all = ...` lines

Comment: If I will set enableSchemaCache=>false, mysql server won't do its job any more!To comment out this code will remove error,but not solve my problem!

Comment: @ponury-kostek that's not right, error is exacly in `try/catch` block, in `echo` statement. Bad exception is catched.